# SSIS retrieves task information from ms project 2010

Tags: ssis, ms-project-server-2010

I have a ms project 2010 file that maintained by the customer in Sharepoint. 
I would like to develop an SSIS script to retrieve information from ms project file and extract to MSSQL database.

SSIS task will be scheduled to run daily.
Looking around with no clue :( any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Describe no clue please.

Comment: I'd start by googling to learn about the format of MS Project files.   the hardest part is figuring out how to extract and make sense of the file.